# Fedora 18 doesn't shutdown , restart or sleep / can not unmount all file systems

Tags: shutdown, unmounting, fedora

When I *do something* (whatever) that results in a shut down, restart or sleep (for example usual shut down or restart, closing the lid, etc.), fedora 18 (x86_64 , GNOME desktop) comes up with an error (below). Can you help me with this?

```
Not all file systems unmounted, 1 left
cannot finalize remaining file systems and devices, giving up
```

#### screenshot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYvEO.jpg]

Should I unmount added devices (other drives) manually before shutdown?

#### EDIT #1

I tried, as user:IBr suggested, to reboot from tty and it worked. So the problem occurs only in GNOME.

Comment: If the same is returned when you go to tty `ctrl` + `alt` + `f2` and do `systemctl shutdown` ?

Comment: What devices are you adding?  Maybe posting the output of `df` will help people understand the problem better.

Comment: You can also try unmounting your added devices manually and seeing if one of them hangs.

Comment: @IBr No. It reboots properly there.

Comment: @drs my drives (volumes) in Windows

Comment: Strange, then it seems that is gnome specific (or gdm to be exact). Still if you are using wubi or anything other for that matter df output would be helpfull.

Comment: I updated the kernel to 3.8.9 and now the problem has gone!(before update it was 3.6.10_4 )